# Calling NtQueryTimerResolution from Silverlight

Tags: multithreading, .net-4.0, silverlight-5.0

I have Silverlight library project with large control in it.

I want to bring PC timer resolution at certain point of time down to 5ms.

I tried to use NtQueryTimerResolution but got exception:

```
Attempt by security transparent method SetupTimer() to call native code through method
NtQueryTimerResolution(UInt32 ByRef, UInt32 ByRef, UInt32 ByRef) failed.  Methods must be
security critical or security safe-critical to call native code.
```

The setup timer method has security attribut on it.. so i dont get whats wrong...

```
    [SecuritySafeCritical]
    private void SetupTimer()
    {
        uint resolution = 0;

        NtSetTimerResolution(50000, true, ref resolution);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution - check "Require elevated trust when running in-browser" in the Silverlight app project properties.